# Which EventDispatcher to use in cocos2d ? Node::EventDispatcher or Director::EventDispatcher?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, symfony-eventdispatcher

Which EventDispatcher to use in cocos2d ? Node::EventDispatcher or Director::EventDispatcher ?
After referencing the official documentation of both Director class and Node class
[Director Class Reference Cocos2d-x](https://cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2/d7/df3/classcocos2d_1_1_director.html#a74a8ad5f80c3406023353d26f9ff901f)
[Node Class Reference Cocos2d-x](https://docs.cocos2d-x.org/api-ref/cplusplus/V3.1/d3/d82/classcocos2d_1_1_node.html#a74a8ad5f80c3406023353d26f9ff901f)
I am a bit confused about, what is the difference between using

```
Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher() // consider this is used inside a class which is derived from Node class
```

or

```
this->getEventDispatcher() // consider this refers to a class derived from Node class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are same. this->getEventDispatcher() calls CCNode's getEventDispatcher() function. It returns _eventDispatcher.

```
_eventDispatcher = _director->getEventDispatcher(); // Check CCNode.cpp
```

So These 3 are same

```
Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWith..

this->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWith..

_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWith..
```

NOTE: I just checked Cocos2d-x 4.0